# Find reason for a subscriber's 'held' status in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud

I've got about 100 subscribers in SFMC with a 'held' status who don't get the transactional emails.

My understanding is that there would've been at least 3 bounces before their status turned to 'held'.

I naturally tried to write an SQL to get the 'bounce category' and 'bounce sub category' for these subscribers. However, it doesn't provide me with any information, i.e., they don't exist in the bounce table.

Can someone tell me why that is, and is there a way I can find out in detail why they have a 'held' status? I'm trying to find out reasons like user unknown, domain unknown, mailbox full, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the documentation - [Bounce Mail Management in Email Studio](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_bounce_mail_management.htm&type=5):

> After Marketing Cloud receives the third soft bounce for a subscriber, their status is set to Held.

I hope you do have SubscriberKeys for those 100 records to retrieve details.

1. You can query [_Bounce](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_data_view_bounce.htm&type=5) Data View:

```sql
SELECT
    AccountID,
    OYBAccountID,
    JobID,
    ListID,
    BatchID,
    SubscriberID,
    SubscriberKey,
    EventDate,
    IsUnique,
    Domain,
    BounceCategoryID,
    BounceCategory,
    BounceSubcategoryID,
    BounceSubcategory,
    BounceTypeID,
    BounceType,
    SMTPBounceReason,
    SMTPMessage,
    SMTPCode,
    TriggererSendDefinitionObjectID,
    TriggeredSendCustomerKey
FROM _Bounce
WHERE SubscriberKey = ''
```

2. You can perform a [Tracking Data Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_as_bounces.htm&type=5) and then download it to the PC and filter out the file in Excel.

Answer (score -1):

Refer to the image for details on how bounce and held works.
[image: Email_Bounce_Flow]

And Held subscribers no longer receive any commercial emails from SFMC. In order to activate these subscribers again, you would have to manually change the status or have them change the status through a webform.

You can refer to _Bounce, _Listsubscribers, _Subscribers dataviews for more understanding about bounce and held.